# Flash Game Actionscript-3 Output Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am making my own game using Actionscript 3 for coding in Flash. The game is about a Runner Character just like Super Mario and Stickyman, who just run, jump, dies.. and so on..
After being very organized by dividing each window of the game in a different Scene, I was still having the problem of executing the piece of code "gotoAndStop()".. That's why I decided to make it much simple by using only one Scene, but each wind of the game in a different frame in the Main Timeline. So I worked on the root, but still getting the same problem that stuck in a white screen!

Anyways, one of the main problem that I am facing here is the Error #1009. Even when I tried to read other topics with the same issue but I didn't find the answer that suites my case.

This is the Error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at HR4_fla::MainTimeline/movePlayer()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Apple/update()
```

Here is the Code:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

import flash.geom.Rectangle;
stop();

var KeyThatIsPressed:uint;
var rightKeyIsDown:Boolean = false;
var leftKeyIsDown:Boolean = false;
var upKeyIsDown:Boolean = false;
var downKeyIsDown:Boolean = false;

var score:int = 0;
var lives:int = 3;
player_mc.health = 100;
player_mc.dead = false;
//var TouchRestartBox:Boolean = false;

var playerSpeed:Number = 8;
var gravity:Number = 2;
var yVelocity:Number = 0;
var canJump:Boolean = false;
var canDoubleJump: Boolean = false;

//var appleCount:int;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, PressAKey);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, ReleaseAKey);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cameraFollowCharacter);

function cameraFollowCharacter(event:Event):void
{
 scrollRect = new Rectangle(player_mc.x - stage.stageWidth/2, player_mc.y - stage.stageHeight/2, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
}

//PressKey function here
function PressAKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
    rightKeyIsDown = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
    leftKeyIsDown = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
    upKeyIsDown = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
    downKeyIsDown = true;
    }
}

//ReleaseKey function here
function ReleaseAKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
    rightKeyIsDown = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
    leftKeyIsDown = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
    upKeyIsDown = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
    downKeyIsDown = false;
    }
}

//stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, GameOver);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlayer);

function movePlayer(event:Event):void
{


if(!rightKeyIsDown && !leftKeyIsDown && !upKeyIsDown)
{
    player_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
}       

if(rightKeyIsDown)
{
player_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
player_mc.x+= playerSpeed;
player_mc.scaleX = 0.59;
}

if(leftKeyIsDown)
{
player_mc.gotoAndStop(2);       
player_mc.x-= playerSpeed;
player_mc.scaleX = -0.59;
}

if(upKeyIsDown && canJump)
{
player_mc.gotoAndStop(3);
yVelocity = -15;
canJump = false;
canDoubleJump = true;
}

if(upKeyIsDown && canDoubleJump && yVelocity > -2)
{
    yVelocity = -13;
    canDoubleJump = false;
}

yVelocity +=gravity;

if(!floor_mc.hitTestPoint(player_mc.x,player_mc.y, true))
{
player_mc.y+=yVelocity;
}

if(yVelocity > 20)
{
yVelocity =20;
}

for(var i:int=0; i<10; i++)
{
    if(floor_mc.hitTestPoint(player_mc.x, player_mc.y, true))
    {
    player_mc.y--;
    yVelocity = 0;
    canJump = true;
    }
}

for(var j:int=0; j<=2; j++)
{
    if(rb.hitTestPoint(player_mc.x, player_mc.y, true))
    {
        player_mc.x = -1703.35;
        player_mc.y = 322.1;
        player_mc.scaleX = 0.59;
        lives = lives - 1;
    }

    if(lives == 0)
    {
//          GameOver();
    // remove all the event listeners
//  stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, GameOver);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlayer);
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, PressAKey);
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, ReleaseAKey);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cameraFollowCharacter);
gotoAndStop(124);
//(root as MovieClip).gotoAndStop(124);
        }
    }


//  appleCount_txt.text = "Apples:" + appleCount;
}


/*function GameOver()
{
//  lives = 3;


// remove all the event listeners
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, GameOver);
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlayer);
stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, PressAKey);
stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, ReleaseAKey);
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cameraFollowCharacter);

//  player_mc.stop();
gotoAndStop(1); // this has your "dead" screen on it.
}*/
```

Can anyone help me solving this problem please?
Thanks

Comment: You miss `return()` right after `gotoAndStop(124)` in your `movePlayer`. For some reason you're checking `hitTestPoint()` twice, and should it be true first time, `gotoAndStop()` is executed, and at the second loop `player_mc` is already null.

Comment: Probably the issue with `Apple.update()` is about the same, but can't tell more precisely without function code.

Comment: Thank you @Vesper for your kind response. Actually I am using hitTestPoint() twice as you said because each one of them has a role. The 1st one was to make the player walk above the ground. While the second one was assigned to the dead hidden line that made the player die when he fall down

Comment: @Vesper Honestly, I am suffering from more than one problem. The two main problems here are:

1- I need to reset the game after a Game Over screen. The Game Over screen should appear after the player dies 3 times sequentially.
That's why I am asking for a help to the gotoAndStop() method that is not working correctly.

2- I need a solution to cut out the error messages of #1009 and the Apple.update()

Comment: @Vesper Another thing is I tried to add a return() right after gotoAndStop(124), but maybe there is a misunderstanding that let me do it wrongly. Can you write it to me? or give me an example please? or any hints? That would make me grateful for your help. Thank you!

Comment: Any Help Guys!? :(

Answer (score 1):

There's a listener still getting executed after the frame change. In that handler, an object is referenced that does not exist on that frame and is thus `null`.
Changing frames only provides visual changes, not necessarily a complete change of state.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13111638)

Comment: @Jacques Snyman I wasn't sure if that also applies to SO's documentation. I guess it's good practice and can't hurt. Answer edited.

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Comment: @null There is a similar but not exactly matching issue. His code flow requests `player_mc` right after `gotoAndStop()` because he has a loop in the listener.